Gazebo simulation performance problem on long run
I'm runnning a neuroevolution algorithm using Gazebo Fortress and ROS 2 Humble, with the Turtlebot 4 robot. In my project I need to run ~10k short runs (1 minute each) and for every run I need to change the starting position of the robot and the objects (yellow cylinders), as shown in the video below.

To do this I have a bash file that calls the gazebo service to set the new position of the objects, the command is the following:
ign service -s /world/arena/set_pose --reqtype ignition.msgs.Pose --reptype ignition.msgs.Boolean --req \"name: 'object$obj_id' position: { x: $(eval echo \\\$OBJECT${obj_id}_X), y: $(eval echo \\\$OBJECT${obj_id}_Y), z: $OBJECT_Z} orientation: { x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 1.0 }\" --timeout 5000
And this command is embedded in the following function in a bash script:
generate_random_position_object() {
    local obj_id=$1

    while true; do
        local x=$(awk -v min=$X_MIN_OBJ -v max=$X_MAX_OBJ -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{srand(seed); print min+rand()*(max-min)}')
        local y=$(awk -v min=$Y_MIN_OBJ -v max=$Y_MAX_OBJ -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{srand(seed); print min+rand()*(max-min)}')


        # Check if the generated position is too close to the TurtleBot4
        local distance_to_turtlebot
        distance_to_turtlebot=$(awk -v x1=$TURTLEBOT_X -v y1=$TURTLEBOT_Y -v x2=$x -v y2=$y 'BEGIN{print sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)}')
    if (( $(echo "$distance_to_turtlebot <= 0.5" | bc -l) )); then
            continue
        fi

        # Check if the generated position is too close to any other objects
        local valid=true
        for existing_obj in OBJECT1 OBJECT2 OBJECT3 OBJECT4 OBJECT5 OBJECT6 OBJECT7; do
            local obj_x=${existing_obj}_X
        local obj_y=${existing_obj}_Y
            local distance_to_obj
            distance_to_obj=$(awk -v x1=${!obj_x} -v y1=${!obj_y} -v x2=$x -v y2=$y 'BEGIN{print sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)}')
        if (( $(echo "$distance_to_obj <= 0.2" | bc -l) )); then
                valid=false
                break
            fi
        done

        if [ "$valid" = true ]; then
        eval "OBJECT${obj_id}_X=$x"
        eval "OBJECT${obj_id}_Y=$y"
            break
        fi
    done

    repeat_ign_command "ign service -s /world/arena/set_pose --reqtype ignition.msgs.Pose --reptype ignition.msgs.Boolean --req \"name: 'object$obj_id' position: { x: $(eval echo \\\$OBJECT${obj_id}_X), y: $(eval echo \\\$OBJECT${obj_id}_Y), z: $OBJECT_Z} orientation: { x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 1.0 }\" --timeout 5000"    
    
    echo "respawned object${obj_id}"
eval echo "\\\$OBJECT${obj_id}_X"
    eval echo "\\\$OBJECT${obj_id}_Y"

}

To change the position of the turtlebot4 I use the following command: ign service -s /world/arena/set_pose --reqtype ignition.msgs.Pose --reptype ignition.msgs.Boolean --req \"name: 'turtlebot4' position: { x: $TURTLEBOT_X, y: $TURTLEBOT_Y, z: $TURTLEBOT_Z } orientation: { x: $TURTLEBOT_QX, y: $TURTLEBOT_QY, z: $TURTLEBOT_QZ, w: $TURTLEBOT_QW}\" --timeout 2000.
What I have noticed is that after some runs I need to repeat these commands to move the robot and the objects multiple times since I keep receiving the output Service call timed out.
This is the entire bash script that I use to handle the single simulation run (sorry if some comments are not in english):
#!/bin/bash

source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash
source /workspace/turtlebot4_minimize_surprise/install/setup.bash 


SIMULATION_TIME=60

# set spawn limit turtlebot4
X_MIN_TB=-1.8
X_MAX_TB=1.8
Y_MIN_TB=-0.2
Y_MAX_TB=3.5

# set spawn limit objects
X_MIN_OBJ=-1.8
X_MAX_OBJ=1.8
Y_MIN_OBJ=2.6
Y_MAX_OBJ=3.5

# variables to store turtlebot4 starting position and orientation
TURTLEBOT_X=0
TURTLEBOT_Y=0
TURTLEBOT_Z=0
TURTLEBOT_QX=0
TURTLEBOT_QY=0
TURTLEBOT_QZ=0
TURTLEBOT_QW=1

# variables to store objects position
OBJECT1_X=0
OBJECT1_Y=0
OBJECT2_X=0
OBJECT2_Y=0
OBJECT3_X=0
OBJECT3_Y=0
OBJECT4_X=0
OBJECT4_Y=0
OBJECT5_X=0
OBJECT5_Y=0
OBJECT6_X=0
OBJECT6_Y=0
OBJECT7_X=0
OBJECT7_Y=0

OBJECT_Z=0.2

# array to store object positions and orientations
declare -A OBJECTS

# function to spawn random position turtlebot
generate_random_position_turtlebot() {
    local x_min=$1
local x_max=$2
    local y_min=$3
local y_max=$4

    # generate random coordinate within limits
    local x=$(awk -v min=$x_min -v max=$x_max -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{srand(seed); print min+rand()*(max-min)}')
    local y=$(awk -v min=$y_min -v max=$y_max -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{srand(seed); print min+rand()*(max-min)}')


    # generate z coordiante based on y values
    local z
    #if (( $(echo "$y > 2.6" | bc -l) )); then # source limit
    #    z=0.11
    #elif (( $(echo "$y >= 1.5 && $y <= 2.6" | bc -l) )); then # slope limits
    #    z=0.09
    #else # cache and nest limit
    #    z=0.04
    #fi

    z=0.15

    # Assegna i valori generati alle variabili globali
    TURTLEBOT_X=$x
TURTLEBOT_Y=$y
    TURTLEBOT_Z=$z
}

# function to spawn a random orientation (z-axis) turtlebot
generate_random_orientation_turtlebot() {
    # Generate a random yaw (rotation around z-axis) between 0 and 2*pi
    local yaw=$(awk 'BEGIN{srand(); print rand() * 2 * 3.14159265359}')

    # Convert the yaw to a quaternion (assuming no pitch or roll)
    TURTLEBOT_QX=0
    TURTLEBOT_QY=0
    TURTLEBOT_QZ=$(awk -v yaw=$yaw 'BEGIN{print sin(yaw / 2)}')
    TURTLEBOT_QW=$(awk -v yaw=$yaw 'BEGIN{print cos(yaw / 2)}')
}

repeat_ign_command() { # repeat the call to an ignition command until is executed correctly
    local command="$1"  # Primo argomento: comando Ignition da eseguire
    local response=""   # Variabile per memorizzare la risposta

    echo "Debug: Il comando passato è -> $command"  # Debug

    # Loop infinito fino a quando non c'è un timeout
    while true; do
        # Esegue il comando e cattura l'output
        echo "Eseguendo comando: $command"
    response=$(eval "$command")

        # Controlla se la risposta è "Service call timed out"
        if [[ "$response" == "Service call timed out" ]]; then
            echo "Timeout del servizio. Ritento..."
            sleep 1  # Ritardo prima di ritentare
            continue
        fi

        # Se la risposta non è un timeout, esci dal loop
        break
    done

    echo "Comando completato con successo o risposta valida ricevuta!"

}


generate_random_position_object() {
    local obj_id=$1

    while true; do
        local x=$(awk -v min=$X_MIN_OBJ -v max=$X_MAX_OBJ -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{srand(seed); print min+rand()*(max-min)}')
        local y=$(awk -v min=$Y_MIN_OBJ -v max=$Y_MAX_OBJ -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{srand(seed); print min+rand()*(max-min)}')


        # Check if the generated position is too close to the TurtleBot4
        local distance_to_turtlebot
        distance_to_turtlebot=$(awk -v x1=$TURTLEBOT_X -v y1=$TURTLEBOT_Y -v x2=$x -v y2=$y 'BEGIN{print sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)}')
    if (( $(echo "$distance_to_turtlebot <= 0.5" | bc -l) )); then
            continue
        fi

        # Check if the generated position is too close to any other objects
        local valid=true
        for existing_obj in OBJECT1 OBJECT2 OBJECT3 OBJECT4 OBJECT5 OBJECT6 OBJECT7; do
            local obj_x=${existing_obj}_X
        local obj_y=${existing_obj}_Y
            local distance_to_obj
            distance_to_obj=$(awk -v x1=${!obj_x} -v y1=${!obj_y} -v x2=$x -v y2=$y 'BEGIN{print sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)}')
        if (( $(echo "$distance_to_obj <= 0.2" | bc -l) )); then
                valid=false
                break
            fi
        done

        if [ "$valid" = true ]; then
        eval "OBJECT${obj_id}_X=$x"
        eval "OBJECT${obj_id}_Y=$y"
            break
        fi
    done

    repeat_ign_command "ign service -s /world/arena/set_pose --reqtype ignition.msgs.Pose --reptype ignition.msgs.Boolean --req \"name: 'object$obj_id' position: { x: $(eval echo \\\$OBJECT${obj_id}_X), y: $(eval echo \\\$OBJECT${obj_id}_Y), z: $OBJECT_Z} orientation: { x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 1.0 }\" --timeout 5000"    
    
    echo "respawned object${obj_id}"
eval echo "\\\$OBJECT${obj_id}_X"
    eval echo "\\\$OBJECT${obj_id}_Y"

}





simulation_id=$1
genome_id=$2

echo -e "\n---------------------------\nGenome ID: $genome_id, Simulation ID: $simulation_id\n---------------------------"

export ROS_DOMAIN_ID=$simulation_id && export IGN_PARTITION=$simulation_id

fastdds shm clean # https://github.com/eProsima/Fast-DDS/issues/2003#issuecomment-1160245640

while true; do
    echo "Update genome_id"
    timeout 10 ros2 param set /ann_controller genome_id  $genome_id # set the genome_id
result=$?
    echo "Exit code: $result"
if [ $result -eq 0 ]; then break; fi
    sleep 2
done

echo "set new genome"
sleep 5

while true; do
    timeout 10 ros2 param set /ann_controller update_genome_id True
    result=$?
echo "Exit code: $result"
    if [ $result -eq 0 ]; then break; fi
    sleep 2
done

echo "enabled genome"

# generate random position turtlebot4
generate_random_position_turtlebot $X_MIN_TB $X_MAX_TB $Y_MIN_TB $Y_MAX_TB
sleep 2

# generate random orientation turtlebot4
generate_random_orientation_turtlebot
sleep 2


# # reset turtlebot4 position
echo "Respawning turtlebot4"
repeat_ign_command "ign service -s /world/arena/set_pose --reqtype ignition.msgs.Pose --reptype ignition.msgs.Boolean --req \"name: 'turtlebot4' position: { x: $TURTLEBOT_X, y: $TURTLEBOT_Y, z: $TURTLEBOT_Z } orientation: { x: $TURTLEBOT_QX, y: $TURTLEBOT_QY, z: $TURTLEBOT_QZ, w: $TURTLEBOT_QW}\" --timeout 2000"
echo "Turtlebot4 respawned"


# Generate and set positions for objects individually
echo "Respawning object1"
generate_random_position_object "1"
#ign service -s /world/arena/set_pose --reqtype ignition.msgs.Pose --reptype ignition.msgs.Boolean --req "name: 'object1' position: { x: $OBJECT1_X, y: $OBJECT1_Y, z: $OBJECT_Z} orientation: { x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 1.0 }" --timeout 2000
#sleep 2

echo "Respawning object2"
generate_random_position_object "2"
#ign service -s /world/arena/set_pose --reqtype ignition.msgs.Pose --reptype ignition.msgs.Boolean --req "name: 'object2' position: { x: $OBJECT2_X, y: $OBJECT2_Y, z: $OBJECT_Z} orientation: { x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 1.0 }" --timeout 2000
#sleep 2

echo "Respawning object3"
generate_random_position_object "3"
#ign service -s /world/arena/set_pose --reqtype ignition.msgs.Pose --reptype ignition.msgs.Boolean --req "name: 'object3' position: { x: $OBJECT3_X, y: $OBJECT3_Y, z: $OBJECT_Z} orientation: { x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 1.0 }" --timeout 2000
#sleep 2

echo "Respawning object4"
generate_random_position_object "4"
#ign service -s /world/arena/set_pose --reqtype ignition.msgs.Pose --reptype ignition.msgs.Boolean --req "name: 'object4' position: { x: $OBJECT4_X, y: $OBJECT4_Y, z: $OBJECT_Z} orientation: { x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 1.0 }" --timeout 2000
#sleep 2

echo "Respawning object5"
generate_random_position_object "5"
#ign service -s /world/arena/set_pose --reqtype ignition.msgs.Pose --reptype ignition.msgs.Boolean --req "name: 'object5' position: { x: $OBJECT5_X, y: $OBJECT5_Y, z: $OBJECT_Z} orientation: { x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 1.0 }" --timeout 2000
#sleep 2

echo "Respawning object6"
generate_random_position_object "6"
#ign service -s /world/arena/set_pose --reqtype ignition.msgs.Pose --reptype ignition.msgs.Boolean --req "name: 'object6' position: { x: $OBJECT6_X, y: $OBJECT6_Y, z: $OBJECT_Z} orientation: { x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 1.0 }" --timeout 2000
#sleep 2

echo "Respawning object7"
generate_random_position_object "7"
#ign service -s /world/arena/set_pose --reqtype ignition.msgs.Pose --reptype ignition.msgs.Boolean --req "name: 'object7' position: { x: $OBJECT7_X, y: $OBJECT7_Y, z: $OBJECT_Z} orientation: { x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 1.0 }" --timeout 2000
#sleep 2

# start simulation
echo -e "start simulation\n"
repeat_ign_command "ign service -s /world/arena/control --reqtype ignition.msgs.WorldControl --reptype ignition.msgs.Boolean --timeout 5000 --req 'pause: false'"
echo "simulation started"

#sleep $SIMULATION_TIME & # simulation time 


# record the rosbag
ros2 bag record -o /workspace/simulation_log/$genome_id/bag \
    /model/turtlebot4/pose \
    /cmd_vel \
    /cliff_sensor_front_left \
    /cliff_sensor_front_right \
    /cliff_sensor_side_left \
    /cliff_sensor_side_right \
    /light_sensor_frontL \
    /light_sensor_frontR \
    /light_sensor_back \
    /hazard_detection \
    /scan \
    /model/object1/pose \
    /model/object2/pose \
    /model/object3/pose \
    /model/object4/pose \
    /model/object5/pose \
    /model/object6/pose \
    /model/object7/pose &

BAG_PID=$!
sleep $SIMULATION_TIME

kill $BAG_PID

sleep 2

echo "save score"
#ros2 topic echo /fitness_topic --once > log2/$genome_id/score.txt # store the score
# path to run the simulation with the HPC workspace
ros2 topic echo /fitness_topic --once > /workspace/simulation_log/$genome_id/score.txt
sleep 2

echo "stop simulation"
repeat_ign_command "ign service -s /world/arena/control --reqtype ignition.msgs.WorldControl --reptype ignition.msgs.Boolean --timeout 5000 --req 'pause: true'" # stop simulation
sleep 2
echo "simulation stopped"

What can be the cause of this problem? I guess it's something related to Gazebo but I'm struggling to figure the source of the problem since the simulation works even after almost 2k runs (with the same Real-Time factor as the beginning).
Update
After enabling the environment variable ING_VERBOSE I can see the following exceptions triggered:

[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] Exception sending a multicast message:Network is unreachable
[parameter_bridge-18] Exception sending a multicast message:Network is unreachable (I get this error message also for other paramter_bridge value, not just 18)

When the service call ended properly this is the output:
Respawning object2
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] Message received requesting a service call
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1]    * Connected to [tcp://127.0.0.1:33453] for sending a response
respawned object2

Otherwise I get the following output, at this link (the call to the same service is done until I don't get back a positive answer from the service call)
I'm running the simulation inside an Apptainer container, can also this affect the simulation (even if these errors starts only after some runs and not from the beginning)?
Update 2
I opened another question related to this here since I tested this problematic behavior without any evolutionary algorithm on top of it.

You can try to run both Gazebo and your bash script with IGN_VERBOSE environment variable set to get some more debugging information (see https://gazebosim.org/api/transport/8/envvars.html).

@azeey thaks for the suggestion. I recevie these messages: [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] Exception sending a multicast message:Network is unreachable, [parameter_bridge-11] Exception sending a multicast message:Network is unreachable. The parameter_bridge number 11 is just an example, I can see the exception for different parameter bridges.

I wonder if, during Discovery, ign-transport is trying to send Multicast packets to network interfaces going through some state ransition. You can try setting IGN_IP=127.0.0.1 on all terminals to limit Discovery to localhost which is unlikely to state changes.

I tried to execute a new simulation with the IGN_IP=127.0.0.1, but I still have the problem that after some runs I have the timeout triggered of the service call. I noticed that this happend for almost any ign service command that I use (both moving a robot/object or stop/start simulation). Anyway, seems that the result of the call is completely independent of the entity that I'm trying to move.
